# Redirect 301 and dynamic search pages generated

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I did some redirects 301 from my old domain to a new domain on new host. It works well, but I'm having a lot of 404's on google webmasters generated by dynamic search pages. E.g.: www.newdomain.com/store/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=60&dir=desc&limit=15&mod‌​e=grid&order=price&p=2&q=makita. But, I think this was crawled in the old domain, because of the searched words and are redirecting now to the new domain. Is there some generic rule to redirect all the others dynamic generated searchs to a specific page like home page on new domain without drop my ranking on google? On my new domain, dynamic search pages have been blocked in robots.txt. Is this way enough to not be crawled again? This is part of my redirect:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*(default|index)\.(html|php|htm)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)(default|main|index)\.(html|php|htm)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^store/?$ http://www.newdomain.com [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^store/folder/?$ http://www.newdomain.com.br/otherfolder/another-folder/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^store/folder1/folder2/?$ http://www.newdomain.com/folder-3/folder-4 [L,NC,R=301]
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So all the dynamic URLs are starting with `/store/catalogsearch/result/index/` or they have other starting paths also?

Comment: @anubhava Yes. All dynamic URLs are starting with /store/catalogsearch/result/index/. There is about 550 URLs now. And every day is increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` to redirect these dynamic URLs to home page of new domain:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /store/catalogsearch/result/index/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks again anubhava for your quick help! One last question, will google automatically remove this 404 errors from webmasters panel and from crawl base?

Comment: Yes it will automatically remove it since we're using `301` here though it will take some days in doing so.

Comment: Thank you so much!